# Height of ui:inputtext

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ui

I have a ui:inputText field that accepts 255 characters.  I want the users to be able to see evertything they type in the field without scrolling.  How can I set the field height so that the input text wraps & the users can see what they input.  Right now I have the following:

```
          <ui:inputText
        aura:id="jobsHeadline"
        maxlength="255"
        class="slds-input requiredField"
        labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
        value="{!v.jobsHeadline}"
        change="{!c.setSubmitButtonState}"
        required="true"
      />
```

Comment: Is there a requirement to use ui:inputText vs lightning:textarea?

Comment: I don't think so.  I am going to test it now in my Sandbox to make sure it works for what we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use inputTextarea it should do what you are looking for

```
<ui:inputTextArea 
aura:id="jobsHeadline"
label="Job Headline"  
value="{!v.jobsHeadline}"
required="true" 
rows="5"/>
```

Hope this helps!!